# How to get my MAC Address programmatically with Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos

I am writing a script that needs to know what the MAC address of the host computer is.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What OS are you on? Without knowing that, no useful answer is likely possible.

Comment: Guess that would help. Mac OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any Ruby built-in function to retrieve that address; you'll likely have to make a system call to list the value (e.g. `ifconfig` on UNIX, `ipconfig /all` on Win32) and parse the output as necessary.

Something like this (untested pseudocode):

```ruby
def mac_address
  platform = RUBY_PLATFORM.downcase
  output = `#{(platform =~ /win32/) ? 'ipconfig /all' : 'ifconfig'}`
  case platform
    when /darwin/
      $1 if output =~ /en1.*?(([A-F0-9]{2}:){5}[A-F0-9]{2})/im
    when /win32/
      $1 if output =~ /Physical Address.*?(([A-F0-9]{2}-){5}[A-F0-9]{2})/im
    # Cases for other platforms...
    else nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Ouch. I thought it would be similar to retrieving the IP Address, which was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Im a seasoned .NET dev struggling with your sample. I whittled it down to a couple lines since it will only run on Macs but it just returns nil.

Comment: @mcass20: oops, botched the win32 regex, just fixed it (at least for Win XP).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I only need the darwin piece as this will only run on a Mac and I just get a nil when I run your regex. I will keep plugging away on it.

Comment: @mcass20: right, misread your last comment =)  Just fixed it by removing the `$` in the darwin regex (didn't see the trailing space in the output).

Comment: Since the MAC address never changes and this method launches an external process, I would memoize the result. (@mac_address ||= begin ... end). I speak from experience on a project that called `ifconfig` repeatedly, and it was a big, unnecessary drain on the servers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a gem called [`macaddr`](http://rubygems.org/gems/macaddr) that does this, but basically it's parsing the output of the system's `ifconfig`. You can see the thread when it was being developed at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/113956

Comment: You can see the full functional code for this library [on GitHub](https://github.com/ahoward/macaddr/blob/master/lib/macaddr.rb)

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems like maerics has given me the code equivalent of that gem.